# Partially "open" SlidingDrawer

Tags: android

I've searched the discussion list (not to mention the interwebs ad nauseum) and I can't seem to find an answer and/or example.

I need to be able to expose part of a ListView on the bottom portion of the screen, and then (like SlidingDrawer) have the rest of the list displayed if the user flings upwards.

SlidingDrawer has the behavior I want, but doesn't seem to have a way of controlling how much it's open or closed (perhaps I'm just missing it).

I've experimented with using Animations to open and close the list.  This works (mostly) except then I have to deal with list scrolling issues as animating the view doesn't seem to reset it's scrollable area to it's visible area.

Does anyone have an example of something like described above?  Or a pointer to bits and pieces to get me going the right direction again?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SlidingDrawer does not support this. You can just create your own :)

Comment: Would going the route of a LinearLayout of items wrapped inside a ScrollView be a reasonable path to the solution?

Comment: Note: the list to display does not contain a large number of items (usually less than 2 screens worth of data) if that is relevant.

Comment: Hi Sasq visit this project on github https://github.com/AshwinNBhanushali/Partial-SlidingDrawer/tree/master/PartialSlidingDrawer

Answer (score 0):

I modified source code of sliding drawer widget and tested its working fine.If anybody wants just give me your email id.
followling attrs.xml will be required in your project were you are going to modified code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SlidingDrawer">
        <attr name="handle" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="content" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your modified version to a site like http://gist.github.com/? I'm trying to implement something similar and would appreciate not having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Little late, but I'd love the modification as well!

Comment: would Love this solution also

Comment: Hey I added my modified slidingdrawer code on https://gist.github.com/AshwinNBhanushali/5261589  you can download it and use it. keep in mind you have declare styleable as described above.

Comment: I hosted a project on git hub visit the link https://github.com/AshwinNBhanushali/Partial-SlidingDrawer/tree/master/PartialSlidingDrawer